# unable to execute .jar files "Could not find the main class"

Tags: java

I have a strange problem. When I try to run any .jar file, I get an error message:

```
---------------------------
Java Virtual Machine Launcher
---------------------------
Could not find the main class: C:\Program Files (x86)\DirBuster\DirBuster.jar.  Program will exit.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I have tried number of .jar files and this error is coming on all files. I have tried re-installing JAVA, running programs through cmd, but the problem still exist. 
Any would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the JAR in question include a class with a public static `main` method?

Comment: You need an entry point into the application. See Java documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: What version of Java are you running with, and what is the compiler level of the jar?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have a main method (has to be declared public static void) - if you have more than one main method in your class, declare the entry point in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd.exe (Command Line Prompt) and run command

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Program Files\DirBuster\DirBuster.jar"
```

This should work. Correct directory names if necessary. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32 is directory where your JDK or JRE installed.

Answer (score 0):

How are yo utrying to run this?  If you're trying to run a jar file, you need to have a Main-Class entry in your manifest with the name of the class to run, and then you can do this:

```
java -jar DirBuster.jar
```

If there's no main class, you might need to do this:

```
java -cp DirBuster.jar MainClass
```

Take a look here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html